# add a session.gc_maxlifetime in .htaccess file

Tags: magento2

i want to add the session.gc_maxlifetime inside the .htaccess file but I can't find which .htaccess file and how to put it inside , is the code below correct

```
<IfVersion < 2.3>
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 2000
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</IfVersion>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David,

As I can understand you need to increase the lifetime value of php session from htaccess file. you can achieve this by adding these lines, if you are running in php module mode:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_flag session.gc_maxlifetime 2000
</IfModule>
```

Helpful link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/.htaccess#L51

Or you can directly change it from .user.ini file by adding below line, if you are running apache with php fpm:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 2000
```

Helpful link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/.user.ini#L3

BTW: Checkout this link if you want to increase cookie lifetime from magento config itself https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/customer-online-options.html